# Eclipse shows unused imports error, but all imports are necessary

Tags: java, eclipse, import

Yesterday, Eclipse began to show "unused imports error", when actually all imports are necessary. If I delete the supposedly unused import, Eclipse prompts me to add it again!

By the way, I can execute my program without problem. How do I resolve this?

Comment: clean it once (project-clean). common problem in eclipse.

Comment: clean it, 
Go to project -> clean -> select your project -> ok

Comment: Tnanks techG and Kaustubh, It works!

Comment: @techG I can't seen an obvious duplicate to close this question. Can you post an answer so we can upvote it and consider this answered?

Comment: @Duncan Did not think about answering it as I believe this is the most common problem any eclipse user faces. So might have been asked before. Anyways added the answer as asked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common problem in eclipse. You need to clean it once.
Go to `project->clean`. Choose any one of the options given (preferably "`clean all projects`" ).
This should solve your problem